# Why does the channel.pipeline().get() returns a null handler in Netty4?

Tags: java, netty

Following this example **[Netty4 confusion with simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365321/netty4-confusion-with-simple-example)** I am trying to get the server's response from a specific handler within the pipeline, like this:

```
ChannelFuture future = CLIENT.start();
CLIENT.sendCmd(MyServerHandler.STATUS_CMD);
future.channel().closeFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
MyClientHandler handler = future.channel().pipeline().get(MyClientHandler.class);
String response = handler.getResponse();
```

getResponse() method is just a property field getter that gets the server's response from channelRead0() method like this:

```
public class MyClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    private String _response;

    public String getResponse()
    {
        return( _response );
    }

    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String input)
        throws Exception
    {
        _response = input;
    }

    // blah...
}
```

While creating **many clients in a loop**, almost half of them throw NullPointerException, because for some reason, **handler** object is NULL!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long debugging, I found out that **pipeline().get()** MUST be invoked prior to **closeFuture().awaitUninterruptibly()**. I am guessing that the handler was already discarded in my original code. But why? The **channel** object was not closed yet!

```
MyClientHandler handler = future.channel().pipeline().get(MyClientHandler.class);
future.channel().closeFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
String response = handler.getResponse();
```

I hope some *"netty4 nerd"* can verify this...?